# Inserting multiple values in rows in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I don't know that why I am unable to get these values inserted into the table.For below table:

```
create table info 
(serial_no number(10), 
name varchar(10));

insert into info(serial_no,name)
values(1,'g'),(2,'u');     /*For this query an error is coming*/
```

ERROR:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Looks like you are trying to use SQL Server syntax. Gordon has given you the way to do it in oracle.  I just chimed in to make the point that each database product has its own implementation of the SQL language.  When faced with syntax issues with rdbms product "A", , you cannot rely on what you know from rdbms product "B".  Check the specific product's SQL Language Reference Manual.

Comment: Syntax is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/INSERT.html). You will notice `insert ... values` only accepts one 'values' expression.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle makes it tricky to insert multiple rows in one statement.  I usually just use `select`:

```
insert into info (serial_no, name)
    select 1, 'g' from dual union all
    select 2, 'u' from dual;
```